# Breaking up existing watershed polygons by flow to individual tributaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, watershed

I have an existing hydroshed dataset (HydroBASIN lev12 basins from the HydroSHED dataset) that I would like to split up further, so that each tributary has its own basin delineated (see below).

[image]

I have tried using the watershed tool in ArcGIS to build these sub-basins, using the same DEM that was used to create the HydroSHED dataset.  This works fine, but the boundaries do not line up exactly with the HydroBASIN lev12 basins due to the DEM pixel size. I'm not sure how they smoothed these basin lines when they created the HydroBASIN dataset.

[image]

I really need to keep the same HydroBASIN lev12 basin outlines (gray), and then split these polygons further into their sub-basins (orange).  I've tried "burning" the lev12 basin lines into the DEM before running the watershed tool, clipping the DEM by the lev12 basin line before running watershed, using Extend Line or Align Feature to manually adjust the lines inside the lev12 basin outline...none of these allow me to keep the same lev12 basin outline.

Any ideas?